# SoapClient returning null but __last_response is populated but still can't create object with simplexml_load_string

Tags: php, soap, soap-client

I have created a SOAP client that is using  a wsdl that I have no control over. I call the webservice and it returns back `null`.

When I copy the XML from `__getLastRequest()` and use it in SOAP UI I get a response back.

When I look at `__last_response` on the soap client I can see an xml string

```
<s:Envelope xmlns:s="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
  <s:Body>
    <GetResponse xmlns="http://tempuri.org/">
      <GetResult>5923946</GetResult>
    </GetResponse>
  </s:Body>
</s:Envelope>
```

When I try passing the `__last_response`  into `simplexml_load_string` an object is not created.

Why can an object not be created with the XML provided in both cases?

Answer (score 0):

SimpleXML cannot load xml strings that have namespaces in it. The solution i found was to remove namespaces. You can do it like this:

`$response=str_replace("<s:","",$response);`

Hope this solves your problem.